# HTML Form onsubmit only working sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, timing, onsubmit

Project Summary: Open Child popup and input information into Form. Onsubmit the information is input into the database, the popup is hidden and parent page is unhidden. The parent page then displays the information from the database.

For the most part the code that I have works, but in some cases when I submit the form the window closes and the information is not added to the database. I'm wondering if I need to add a delay in somewhere so that there is time to insert the data into the database, but I've never worked with any timing code and am unsure of where it would need to go. Does anyone have any idea why it will only add to the database sometimes? The problem times tend to be the first few times the form is used and when trying to enter the same information right after one another.

The code related to the form looks like this:

```
    <script>
    var db = window.openDatabase("DB1", "", "DB", 1024 * 1000)

    function closeSelf() {
        document.forms['moneyorder_form'].submit();
        hide(document.getElementById('AddMoneyOrderPopup'));
        unHide(document.getElementById('MoneyOrdersMain'));
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#moneyorder_form').submit(function () {

            insertMO($('#moCNumber').val(), $('#moCAmount').val(), "MoneyOrder");
            renderMoneyOrders();
            return false;
        });
        renderMoneyOrders();
    });


</script>

<div data-role="page" id="AddMoneyOrderPopup">
    div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <h2 style="text-align:center">Money Order</h2>
        <form method="get" id="moneyorder_form" name="moneyorder_form" onsubmit="closeSelf()">
            <div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <p style="text-align:center; display:inline"><b>Number</b></p>
                    <p><input type="number" required="required" step="1" id="moCNumber" name="moCNumber"></p></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <p style="text-align:center; display:inline"><b>Amount</b></p>
                    <p><input type="number" required="required" min=".01" step=".01" id="moCAmount" name="moCAmount"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a">
        <input type="submit" data-role="button" data-theme="a" value="Add" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would make sure that the data are not added to the database because they could be added but just the parent page does not show them.

Comment: I've checked that. They aren't being added at all.

Comment: then you need to debug form submission on the server. the client side script and the markup do not seem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the new HTML5 SQL API and not a server-backed database.
If this is the caes, HTML5 supports a `transaction` function that accepts an optional error and success callbacks:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  // executeSql
}, opt_errorCallback, opt_successCallback);
```

So instead of adding timers, I would create two callbacks and only display the new record if the success callback has been called.